# Unable to get Custom Field Values by get_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, post

In my wordpress post, I have a Custom Field: ***Message to Organizer***:
[image]

When I check my `wp_postmeta` table, it is reflected their as:
[image]

Then when I try to use `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Message to Organizer', true);`
I am getting nothing as a result.
I just dont get where I am getting wrong? Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure meta keys are allowed spaces. Try save it as message_to_organizer and try again.

Comment: The thing is, this is a frontend field. I know without spaces its working, but then I wont be able to manage the front-end field. Actually these fields are coming from a plugin settings.

Answer (score 3):

It should works correctly with spaces in `meta_key`. So, the only thing, that could be wrong is your `$post->ID` value. Make sure, that `$post->ID` content correct value in the place, where you use the `get_post_meta` function.

Comment: I have found the issue. When I put in a manual post ID say 2477 in this case, it is getting me the value. But when I am using the $post->ID, its not working. Since I am using this `get_post_meta` inside a function that is used for `transition_post_status` so I think that values are being saved in postmeta later and the `transition_post_status` is being triggered before it. Because I am using $post->ID for others as well within the same function and it is working fine. Only having problem with custom fields meta values.